# SQL Query GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following record and values:

```
create table student (
  LastName      varchar(40),
  FirstName     varchar(40),
  SID           number(5),
  SSN           number(9),
  Career        varchar(4),
  Program       varchar(10),
  City          varchar(40),
  Started       number(4),

  primary key (SID),
  unique(SSN)
);

create table enrolled (
  StudentID     number(5),
  CourseID      number(4),
  Quarter       varchar(6),
  Year          number(4),

  primary key (StudentID, CourseID),
  foreign key (StudentID) references student(SID),
  foreign key (CourseID) references course(CID)
);

insert into student
    values ( 'Brennigan', 'Marcus', 90421, 987654321, 'UGRD', 'COMP-GPH', 'Evanston', 2001 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Patel', 'Deepa', 14662, null, 'GRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Evanston', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Snowdon', 'Jonathan', 08871, 123123123, 'GRD', 'INFO-SYS', 'Springfield', 2005 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Starck', 'Jason', 19992, 789789789, 'UGRD', 'INFO-SYS', 'Springfield', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Johnson', 'Peter', 32105, 123456789, 'UGRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Chicago', 2004 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Winter', 'Abigail', 11035, 111111111, 'GRD', 'PHD', 'Chicago', 2003 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Patel', 'Prakash', 75234, null, 'UGRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Chicago', 2001 );
insert into student
    values ( 'Snowdon', 'Jennifer', 93321, 321321321, 'GRD', 'COMP-SCI', 'Springfield', 2004 );

insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 1020, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 1092, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (11035, 8772, 'Spring', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (75234, 3201, 'Winter', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (08871, 1092, 'Fall', 2005);
insert into enrolled
    values (90421, 8772, 'Spring', 2006);
insert into enrolled
    values (90421, 2987, 'Spring', 2006);
```

My goal is to: List (pairs of) students that have taken the same class together.

Expected output:

```
StudentID   COURSEID
11035   1092
8871    1092
11035   8772
90421   8772
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Which is your database?

Comment: I use Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Table `course` is missing in the create script.

Comment: "same class together" is referring to COURSEID

Comment: Please add expected output for given set of data.

Comment: @techdo, I just did. Thanks.

Comment: Why do I feel you are asking us to code this for you? Where is your existing query for getting this data?

Comment: @Blue, NO I do not. I just need help getting started. Some hints, anything...

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the query:

```
select * from(
  select a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.StudentID, b.COURSEID, count(*) over (partition by b.COURSEID) CNum
  from STUDENT a inner join enrolled b on a.SID=b.StudentID
  ) x where CNum=2
```